# How can I get the number of records for today in five-minute intervals?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I have a column named `creation_timestamp` on a table named `bank_payments`, I would like to break today into five-minute intervals, and then query the database for the count in each of those intervals.

I'm going to read this manually (i.e. this is not for consumption by an application), so the output format does not matter as long as I can use it to get the five-minute time period, and the count of records in that period.

Is it possible to do this entirely on the side of the database?

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It's probably best to use a tally table

Comment: yes, using cron job for run query every 5 mintes

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I added more information to the question. Thanks a lot for telling me what to fix, rather than just downvoting/voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group by your records in table on 5 min interval then you can try this:

```
SELECT col1, count(col1), creation_timestamp
FROM bank_payments
WHERE DATE(`creation_timestamp`) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_timestamp) DIV 300, col1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Here is one method:

```
select sec_to_time(floor(time_to_sec(time(datetimecol)*5/60))), count(*)
from t
where t.datetimecol >= curdate() and
      t.dattimeecol < curdate() + interval 1 day
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, but what does the first column mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting an output like

```
|          begin_time |            end_time | cnt |
|---------------------|---------------------|-----|
|          2015-12-28 | 2015-12-28 00:05:00 |   1 |
| 2015-12-28 01:00:00 | 2015-12-28 01:05:00 |   4 |
| 2015-12-28 01:05:00 | 2015-12-28 01:10:00 |   1 |
| 2015-12-28 02:55:00 | 2015-12-28 03:00:00 |   4 |
| 2015-12-28 03:05:00 | 2015-12-28 03:10:00 |   1 |
| 2015-12-28 03:10:00 | 2015-12-28 03:15:00 |   1 |
```

Then

```
select
    begin_time,
    end_time,
    sum(case when creation_timestamp between begin_time and end_time then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from (
    select @r begin_time, @r := @r + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE end_time
    from (select @r := curdate()) r,
    (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) a1, #4
    (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) a2, #6 * 4 = 24
    (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) a3, #4 * 24 =  96
    (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) a4 #3 * 96 =  288
) x,
(select creation_timestamp from bank_payments) y
group by begin_time, end_time
```

If you only need those intervals having count > 0 then

```
select
    begin_time,
    end_time,
    sum(case when creation_timestamp between begin_time and end_time then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from (
    select @r begin_time, @r := @r + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE end_time
    from (select @r := curdate()) r,
    (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) a1, #4
    (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) a2, #6 * 4 = 24
    (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) a3, #4 * 24 =  96
    (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1) a4 #3 * 96 =  288
) x,
(select creation_timestamp from bank_payments) y
group by begin_time, end_time 
having sum(case when creation_timestamp between begin_time and end_time then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab70c8/10)